# Ember.js: transition to nested route calls which action?

Tags: ember.js, controller, nested, routes

I have followed this guide for nested routes: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resources

I have a nested route:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('account', function() {
        this.route('register');
    });
});
```

In my index template I call an action of my index controller which is this one:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        doRegistration: function(){
            this.transitionToRoute('account.register');
        }
    }
});
```

Everything works up to here, and my AccountRegisterController even gets instantiated I think as the following gets logged into console:

```
App.AccountRegisterRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model){
        console.log('setting up controller'+controller);
    }
});
```

Here is my AccountRegisterController:

```
App.AccountRegisterController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        register: function(){
            console.log('account register');
        },
        index: function(){
            console.log('account index');
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is neither of the actions of the controller gets called. Why? How can I tell `transitionTo(...)` what action to call? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

'transitionTo' doesn't call an action, it just changes the route.

In order to have code be executed you can do it in the different hooks on the route.

you could have:

```
App.AccountRegisterRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function() {
        console.log('setting up controller'+controller);
        //write any register code here
    }
});
```

Or you can send the action to the route hooks:

```
App.AccountRegisterRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function() {
        this.send('register');
        this.transitionTo('account.welcome');

    }
});
```

What you probably want to be doing is first performing the action, then transiting without having an intermediary route. Like so:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        doRegistration: function(){
            //code to register user here.
            this.transitionToRoute('account.welcome');
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to be able to reuse your registration controller, you can define it as an action in the parent controller which will then bubble up like if you do not define it in the child controllers or routes:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        doRegistration: function(){
            //code to register user here.
            this.transitionTo('account.welcome');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: sry, I don't get this. If I put my code into `beforeModel` inside the route, how do I know if I execute code for registration or code for login? My controller handles both cases, that's why I have more than one action inside my controller. I don't get this controller thing. Why can't I just call some action? I mean, how does `beforeModel` know if I want to execute the code of `indexAction` or `registerAction` as they are defined in my `AccountRegisterController`?